# Does changing built variant from debug to release makes effect on signed APK?

Tags: android

I want to generate a signed APK do I need to select any of the release variant to generate the apk or I don't need to select any thing from here just generate singed APK from Buid menu? I am uploading an image which android atudio shows me.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXzSs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy you can just follow the generate signed apk flow from the build menu section.

It will create the signed apk for you. As the screenshot you given was showing emulator devices which might create an issue while creating the release.

Here is the complete flow for the generating signed apk using android studio:-

**Step1:-** Create certificate.jks from the build menu, select Generate signed apk.
fill all the details required and same that certificate somewhere safe, because it's very important for future updates.

Also, remember the keystore password and alias name you entered.

Here is the screenshot:-

[image]

**Step 2:-** Put the following code in your build.gradle file under the android section as follows:-

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'YourAliasName'
        keyPassword 'password@123'
        storeFile file('D:/certificate.jks')
        storePassword 'password@123'
    }
}
```

**Step 3:-** Now finally select build variant option to release from the settings as follows:-

[image]

Its all done, now wait for a while it will build a release apk for you max in a minute after gradle sync complete.!!!

Comment: Thanks, Please check my image android studio shows me 4 types of release (release-arm64-v8a, release-armeabi-v7a, release-x86, release-x86_64) whixh one is need to be selected?